# Globalize duplicated locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize

When I create a new admin user, there are three objects of translations:

```
Admin.last.translations.map(&:locale) # => [:ru, :uz, :uz]
```

Why are the locales duplicated?

Example:

```
admin.position_uz = 'CTO'
admin.position_ru = 'CTO'
admin.save!

admin.translations.count = 3
admin.translations.first.position = 'CTO'
admin.translations.second.position = 'Another value or empty'
admin.translations.third.position = 'CTO'
```

Every time the locale is set to `uz`, it shows the second variant.

Admin translations loo like

```
[
  #<Admin::Translation id: 1, admin_id: 2, locale: "ru", position: "CTO", created_at: "2019-01-16 06:24:17", updated_at: "2019-01-16 06:30:31">,
  #<Admin::Translation id: 2, admin_id: 2, locale: "uz", position: "Board Member", created_at: "2015-07-26 20:42:18", updated_at: "2015-07-26 20:42:18">,
  #<Admin::Translation id: 3, admin_id: 2, locale: "uz", position: "CS manager", created_at: "2019-01-16 06:24:17", updated_at: "2019-01-16 07:09:21">
]
```

Comment: What's the result of `Admin.last.translations`? How does your translations table look like (for that user)?

Comment: @Stefan Updated my post

Comment: Apparently, there a two translations for locale `uz` – `"Board Member"` (created in 2015) and `"CS manager"` (created recently).

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I see, but why `Board Member` added?

Comment: I don't know where it comes from, but your translation data has been corrupted somehow. Removing the duplicate entry will likely fix the issues. Furthermore, it seems like your translations table is missing an index to prevent duplicates at the database level. You should check that.

Comment: @Stefan yes, I removed all old data, and it fixed, thanks!